# CSS can't animate rotation

Tags: css, animation, rotation, transform

I want to animate rotation of my object. I use `perspective` & `preserve-3d` properties, and try `transform:rotate(15deg)` or any degrees manually and it works fine

Then I use addClass to trigger the animation. I have 4 properties to animate (scale, rotate, opacity & position). The position, opacity, & scale works just fine, but the rotation aren't.

I already tried to delete the position, opacity, & scale just to test the rotation alone, and still not working.

```
.flip-animation {
  animation: flipper 2s;
    }


@keyframes flipper {
  0% {
    transform:
      rotateY(0deg)  
      scale(0,0)
      translate(0px, 1000px);
    opacity:0;
  };
  100%{
    transform:
      rotateY(900deg) /*any number not working*/
      scale(1,1)
      translate(0px, 0px);
    opacity:1;
  };
  }
```

Full Code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/louislugas/pen/ExwrMom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `;` between keyframes

```css
.flip-animation {
  animation: flipper 2s;
    }


@keyframes flipper {
  0% {
    transform:
      rotateY(0deg)  
      scale(0,0)
      translate(0px, 1000px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    transform:
      rotateY(900deg) /*any number not working*/
      scale(1,1)
      translate(0px, 0px);
    opacity:1;
  };
  }
```

Comment: dang it works! thanks! it's confusing to debug because only affecting the rotation